# Populate Dynamically Created Dropdown with Options from PHP array using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, combobox

I created a javascript dropdown using this code:

```
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var element3 = document.createElement("select");
element3.name = "prddrop[]";
element3.id = "prddrop[]";
cell3.appendChild(element3);
```

My problem is to populate that combobox with data coming from a PHP associative array.

```
<?php
if(isset($prods) && count($prods) > 0)
{ 
foreach($prods as $key=>$p)
    {
$productID= $p['pid'];
$productName=$p['pname'];
   }
}
?>
```

Please Help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery with something like this if that dosent bother you,

```
          jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
                jQuery('select[name="' + populatedElement + '"]')
                        .append(jQuery("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", key)
                        .text(value));
            });
```

It will dynamcially add values to your select box.

Comment: I did not understand, can you make a fiddle for me?

Comment: well i havent tested it on fiddle exactly but data will be array and PopulatedElement will be name of your select box where as key and value are normal array (key=>value), i have done same code on my local , following my perspective

Comment: Thanks I used json to get the data from my array and the rest follows. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX, to load it on the fly. Or you could always echo your PHP out directly into your script.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/